# Why is the name of file VS linker processing wrong? How can I change it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, glfw

I'm trying to build a project using GLFW library. Unfortunately, I can't do it because Visual Studio linker gives me the error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: can't open file "o le32.lib"
```

Actually, there's no file with name "o le32.lib", but the file "ole32.lib" definitely exists. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this issue?
I'm not sure it's necessary, but I post here my very short piece of code:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void main()
{
    glfwInit();
    //Set up the configuration of GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); //First arg - parameter, second arg - its value
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

}
```

Comment: Have you added glfw.lib as a dependency to your project? if not it can be  a cause of the problem)

Comment: Probably a mistake / typo in your project settings.

Comment: @kirill21 are glfw3dll.lib and glfw.lib the same things? When I downloaded the folder with library from the official website, I didn't find there glfw.lib or glfw3.lib. The name of the folder I downloaded was "glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64". Was I mistaken in my actions?

Comment: @natChan "are glfw3dll.lib and glfw.lib the same things" - I think yes, There are the same. Have you added it to the dependencies of your MS VS project?  You have to add this dependency to the project and indicate include dirs(in settings of Visual Studio project)

Comment: @natChan Also you should add glew.dll to the bin directory of your project.

Comment: I don't think any of the comments about glew are the fix for `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: can't open file "o le32.lib"` My expectation is this is caused by a typo in the linker settings for your project.

Comment: ole32.lib is most likely a 3d party of glfw.lib. This is hardly a problem with the project settings.

Comment: ole32.lib is a core library of the OS. ole32, oleaut32 : OLE is the basis for ActiveX, DCOM, etc. Many of the newer OS APIs are COM objects

Comment: ***This is hardly a problem with the project settings.*** It could have easily have been a typo (accidental space typed) in the list of linker dependencies where each .lib file is listed. I just created the same error message in a few seconds by editing the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies list.